# An R function to dynamically generate another R function using a character vector

Tags: r, r-caret

I am writing a wrapper function around the `rBayesianOptimization` and `caret` R packages. The question described below is part of an internal step inside the main wrapper function. I need to pass the hyperparameters for a particular model (this is what `input` represents below) to a function that will be sampled in the Gaussian process model. The hyperparameters are currently stored in a character vector.

Is there a way to use a character vector to dynamically generate a function in R? I need a function that actually creates another function. For example,

```
# start with this...
input <- c("a","b")

# ...and an intermediate function generates this
test_function <- function(a=a,b=b) {
  d <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)
}
```

Additionally, the solution would need to be able to handle inputs of various lengths and content. So something like this should also work,

```
# start with this...
input <- c("c","d","e","f")

# ...and an intermediate function generates this
test_function <- function(c=c,d=d,e=e,f=f) {
  d <- data.frame(c=c,d=d,e=e,f=f)
}
```

This is a toy example, but it is sufficient to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you're looking for a function that creates a function, where the second function takes arguments with names as in `input` (given to the first function) and values, maybe numeric, labeled by those arguments. If that's right, how about this?

```
create_fun <- function(input) {
  funargs <- paste(input, collapse=', ')
  dfargs <- paste0(input, '=', input, collapse=', ')
  funstr <- paste0(
    sprintf("function(%s) {", funargs),
    sprintf("data.frame(%s)", dfargs),
    "}")
  eval(parse(text=funstr))
}
# example applications:
create_fun(c('a','b'))(a=1, b=8)
##   a b
## 1 1 8
create_fun(c('x','y','z'))(y=1, z=8, x=4)
##   x y z
## 1 4 1 8
```

Comment: This is perfect. I updated my original question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple answer to the simple example you posted. It sounds like your real work might need a more complicated approach, but this might help. I'm sure there are other ways to do this faster.

```
input <- c("c","d","e","f")

test_function <- function(inputVec) {
  df <- data.frame(inputVec[1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(df)[1] <- inputVec[1]
  if(length(inputVec) == 1) {
    return(df)
  }
  else if(length(inputVec) > 1) {
    for(i in seq(2, length(inputVec), 1)) {
      dfNew <- data.frame(inputVec[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      names(dfNew) <- inputVec[i]
      df <- dplyr::bind_cols(df, dfNew)
    }
    return(df)
  }
}

testDF <- test_function(inputVec = input)

print(testDF)
##  c d e f
##1 c d e f
```

Comment: This does do what I asked (hence the +1), but I realize I did not ask exactly what I meant to in my original question. The response by @pangia is what I had in mind. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer -- probably not useful for the original problem, but I'm posting it anyway as I spent a little time figuring it out :).

One way to do it is based on the code in `rlang::new_function`:

```
doit <- function(i) {
  args <- setNames(lapply(i, as.name),i)
  fn <- call("function", as.pairlist(args), as.call(c(as.name("data.frame"), args)))
  eval(fn, parent.frame())
}

# output
> doit("A")
function (A = A) 
data.frame(A = A)
> doit(c("A", "B"))
function (A = A, B = B) 
data.frame(A = A, B = B)
> doit(c("A", "B", "C"))
function (A = A, B = B, C = C) 
data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C)
```